# Chrome dev tools: displaying cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

1. Visit a random site, for example example.com
2. Open dev tools, application -> cookies
3. Make sure that it's empty
   [image: no cookie]
4. Open console tab, make a fetch request to a random website, for example `fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')`
5. Open application -> cookies again and notice cookies from the domain from step 4.
   [image: have cookie]

Many times a day I clear a website's cookies for debugging purposes. But in Chrome clearing one website's cookies affects clearing other sites' cookies as well and it clears my sessions on other websites, which is not what I want.

Is it a bug or a feature in Chrome? I think that it's a bug and cookies from other domain shouldn't be shown, but maybe I miss something.

P.S. Firefox don't show cookies from other domains.

Comment: `api.chucknorris.io` isn't setting a cookie for me.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you need to visit chucknorris.io first for cookie to be set in the browser. After that repeat the steps.

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is that the list of URLs under the 'Cookies' entry is the page that made a request to the origin server for the cookies shown. If you look in the network traffic you can see the the URLs in the 'Cookies' list are the referer of the requests to the origin servers, whose response sets the cookie. This is a common method for tracking cookies to be set. A.com in the 'Cookies' URL list will have some page with lots of IMG or Script or iframe elements that make requests to the domains in the list of cookies and the responses from those domains set the cookies. What I found confusing is that the Chrome documentation (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies) refers to the list of URLs under the 'Cookies' entry as 'Origins'. They are not the cookies origin as defined in RFC 6265, they are the referer page that made the requests to the cookie origin servers.